# Perforce: Avoid using the same absolute local path on all dev machines?

Tags: build-automation, perforce, perforce-client-spec

I'm new to Perforce (but am fairly experienced with other systems, mostly SVN).
Now I'm trying to make a simple windows bat build script that needs to check in some build results (controversial to some, I know, but please try to ignore as it's a different discussion). I'm using p4 for this. The problem is that it seems I either:

- Use the same "client" as on other machines (the -c option). This will have a "root", which looks like it specifies the absolute path where the working copy goes locally. Seems rather "wtf?" to me...
- Interactively create a "client" for each machine (matching the local file system layout). The interactivity is obviously a deal-breaker for an automated script.

Can I somehow just use the current directory, like I can with SVN?
Is there a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a workspace with a root of *null* and map the depot to that client.  Here's an example client spec:

```
Client: client_name

Update: 2010/10/20 14:18:23

Access: 2010/10/20 14:20:53

Owner:  raven

Host:   ravens-pc

Description:
    Created by raven.

Root:   null

Options:    noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked modtime rmdir

SubmitOptions:  leaveunchanged

LineEnd:    local

View:
    //depot/... //client_name/...
```

The first thing your script should do is switch to this client by setting the $P4CLIENT$ environment variable:

`p4 set p4client=client_name`

You script will now be working in the context of that client.  *By virtue of the fact that you have specified a root of null, any syncing that you do will be relative to the current directory*.  So, if you sync //depot/foo/... while in C:\bar, your files will appear in C:\bar\foo.

The last thing your script should do is clear the P4CLIENT variable to restore the system to the default client specification:

`p4 set p4client=`

Comment: Yes, this is essentially what I meant in my own answer. That aside, is there a difference in setting the environment variable and using -c client_name ?

Comment: @Niklas: I don't know what you mean by "-c client_name".  I take it you are referring to passing that switch to a command, but I can't figure out which one.

Comment: Here it is: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/o.gopts.html#1040647

Comment: @Niklas: Nice!  I was not aware of that.  By all means, screw the environment variable and use that -c switch.

Comment: How does perforce keep track of what is synced. Do we have to use p4 sync -f for every new location??

Comment: @Keerthi Perforce tracks the synced state of a client in its database.  So if you use a client on multiple hosts you will need to do a force sync (if you need to use the files).  You can so "p4 sync -f #have" get everything that Perforce thinks you have.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest creating a new client each time with a client template.  First, manually create a client with the view as you'd like it in the actual build clients.  Don't specify the Owner, Client, or Root fields.  Then, each time you want a new client have it do the following:

```
p4 client -t my-client-template-name -o my-unique-client-name >clientspec.txt
p4 client -i <clientspec.txt
```

Where `my-client-template-name` is the client you created in the first step.  Of course, when you're done be sure to do the following:

```
p4 client -d my-unique-client-name
```

Comment: Why two lines. Pipe the output. """p4 client -t my-client-template-name -o my-unique-client-name | p4 client -i"""

Answer (score 1):

You can interactively create a client without an editor by using `p4 client -i`:

> The -i flag causes a client specification to be read from the
>     standard input.  The user's editor is not invoked

So in your builtscript you'd have a template for the client view, which you modify on the fly for the current build machine and pass it to `p4 client -i`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about that, but it would require string processing which would require either: 1. More batch script kung fu than I will ever develop, 2. A change of script language or 3. Use of more external tools.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can pre-create a client workspace with a root directory of "null", which will cause perforce to use current working directory as root.

Comment: That was my first thought, but don't you have to specify some path in the client space (mapping depot-paths to local paths)?